# NVM doesn't seem to be pointing to the right user when being ran from a service

Tags: bash, shell, service, raspbian, nvm

I have a situation where I have a service that runs a shell script, that in turns uses NVM to set my current Node environment to 8.16.0. The script works fine but when I start the service that is supposed to do the same it fails due to there not being a Node version 8.16.0, despite it being installed in my current user. Is there something I might have missed with how NVM behaves that might affect this?

I've already tried setting the user in the service as the desired user.

Here's the service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=script startup service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=1

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/job.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here's the part of job.sh giving me trouble:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm use 8.16.0
```

I expect it to change nvm to version 8.16.0, instead I get a message saying that that version is not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing

```
#! /bin/sh
```

to

```
#! /bin/bash
```

as suggested by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32502108/7708264